# Looking for a method to save ID of the created object

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-intent

Example:
I have created an object and it saved in Table1 with id.

How i need to write logic to use this key as a foreign key for objects in another Table2.

Like in gmail app. List of letters push the letter and get the data for EXACT pushed letter.

Comment: and what do you have problems with?

Comment: You have Table1 object with Id, so you have reference to object, which will give you id stored in database, What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @pskink how i can save a link to pushed object?

Comment: see the return value of `SQLiteDatabase#insert` method

Comment: @vikashkumarpandey i have founded what i was looking for. U can check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for cursor loader / cursor adapter constructions. It helps take data and inflate it in UI.

I didn't know that it has to work like this:
Activity -> Content Resolver -> Content Provider + URI Matcher -> Query

And after getting cursor inflate it in the list

Also if we want to be forwarded to another activity after clicked on some element for example of the list with method withAppendedId(). We need to use intent on first activity and getData() and getIntent() in the second activity.